# "call the race" in the election

Tags: american-english

What is the meaning of `call` in `call the race`? I know that `call the race` roughly means announcing the winner, right? I found this term appears frequently in the many artiles about the US presidential election. For example:

> The Associated Press has not called this race.

> Races are called when a winner is clear.

Comment: Right, announce. What the media announces does not determine the winner. The winner is determined by official vote counts by the states and the subsequent procedures laid out in the Constitution.

Answer (score 6):

'Call' has a bewildering number of senses, some conflicting. [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/call), for instance, gives (their sense 8)

> **call** ... [8] [verb] If someone in authority calls something such as a meeting, rehearsal, or election, they arrange for it to take
> place at a particular time.

But this of course is not the sense involved here; your examples are closer to [Macmillan's](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/call_1#call_1__65) sense 9:

> **call** ... [9] to say [with conviction] what you think will happen, for example in politics or business
>
> [often as] *hard/difficult to call*:
>
> - The situation in the East is hard to call.

However, your [Associated Press](https://www.ap.org/en-us/topics/politics/elections/how-we-call-races) quotes, as their article makes clear, certainly uses 'call' to mean 'announce a definite result' (in the expressions 'call a race / an election ...') rather than 'predict a near-certain result'. I've not found this in a dictionary (though the far broader 'announce' is usually given).

[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/call) gets closest of those I've looked at:

> **call** [15] To indicate or characterize **accurately** in advance; predict:
>
> - *It is often difficult to call the outcome of an election.* [bolding mine]

Comment: If I set the default language of Google Search to Chinese, `The Associated Press has not called this race` is displayed as `The Associated Press 尚未公布此选举的结果`, which can be translated into `The Associated Press has not announced the results yet. ` by the word-for-word translation.

Comment: But how does it translate 'Five all with ten minutes to go. This match is too close to call'?

Comment: Actually, *call* in the sense that the OP is asking about has become a semi-technical term which stands for something that is very highly reliable and thus more than a **mere** prediction (of the kind that may be made before the election), but it still **is** a prediction of sorts: it predicts what the final, official result will be.

Comment: Yes, but even the 'semi-technical term' is ill-defined (especially when it comes to fake / overly optimistic calls!). The fact that some called results are later shown to be erroneous shows this. And the different senses shown in dictionaries shows ill-definition of 'call' in general. It's good from a linguistics perspective (and beneficial societally, I'll claim) to see AP give a clear specifying definition here (though other platforms will doubtless not comply). Unclear language facilitates duplicity.